# How to prepare modules that depends on each other for Marketplace

Tags: magento2

Let's assume that I have module A and B.
Second(B) one depends on the first(A) one how can I prepare them for Magento Marketplace?

For one module it's easy I just zip it and place it in Marketplace also while doing that Magento has option to add packages? Is this a solution for dependent modules?

Answer (score 0):

In **composer.json**, you can write dependency as follows.

```
...
"require": {
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf":"*"
}
...
```

Where `tecnickcom/tcpdf` is another module on which your module depends.

But to know value like `tecnickcom/tcpdf`, we need to refer installation or user guide of that another module in marketplace. So we may not able to get it for all modules.

Comment: Can this be done by package not extension. I'm asking because at some point I don't want to keep ale functionalities as modules and I don't want to keep them in external repos like github etc.?